# Play Core Library giving Non-Fatal

Tags: android, google-play-core

I recently updated my app with the latest Play core library version 1.8.2 for consuming the Native In-App review API. But, since updating the Play core version to this, I've started receiving a huge chunk of non-fatal reported via Firebase Crashlytics. The stack trace for the same is

```
Non-fatal Exception: com.google.android.play.core.internal.ar: Failed to bind to the service.
       at com.google.android.play.core.internal.aq.a(aq.java:82)
       at com.google.android.play.core.internal.aj.a(aj.java:4)
       at com.google.android.play.core.internal.ah.run(ah.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

I'm not able to understand this and I'm not sure why this would come after updating the play core version. Since I'm not able to reproduce this as well, I suspect this may cause issues to the users using my app. The point to be noted here is that this is specifically coming in Android 8, 9 and 10 versions and 98% of total cases are reported on Xiaomi devices, while 1% cases are for OnePlus devices as well.

Here's my app-level `build.gradle` for play core dependency

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.2'
```